# Why do I receive the error "The data object type specified in the DataObjectTypeName property of ObjectDataSource 'ods' could not be found"?

Tags: asp.net, objectdatasource

I have an `ObjectDataSource` on an ASP.NET WebForms page, that also has a data-bound control. The declarative syntax for the ODS looks like this:

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource runat="server" ID="ods"
    TypeName="Transaction"
    SelectMethod="GetTransactionList"
    SelectCountMethod="GetTransactionListCount"
    DataObjectTypeName="Transaction.TransactionViewModel"
    UpdateMethod="UpdateTransaction"
    >
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Data is successfully retrieved from the data source; however, when an Update operation is attempted, this error occurs:

> The data object type specified in the DataObjectTypeName property of ObjectDataSource 'ods' could not be found

The type `Transaction.TransactionViewModel` is `public`, and it is visible from the code-behind of this page. Why can't the `ObjectDataSource` find it?

Comment: This question is confusing. You answered your own question using second-person pronouns instead of first-person, and answered it in under a minute. Was this some mistake, or did something go haywire in SO?

Comment: @jwis [Phrasing self-answered questions (and the self-answers) just the same as open questions is, I believe, the correct thing to do](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/87723/151211). I agree I may however have put my own answer in too quickly this time.

Comment: Right, I'm not discounting the validity of the question and answer; I was just confused because you referred to yourself in the second person (using you/your) instead of the first person (I/my).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your type specification is incorrect for an **inner** class. To specify an **inner** class, you need to use `+`, not `.`, this:

```
DataObjectTypeName="Transaction+TransactionViewModel"
```

Comment: I was also having the similar issue and it's resolved by correcting the DataObjectTypeName's typo. Life saving post for me. Thanks @AakashM

Answer (score 0):

u must write the Object type used in there..
ie is u want all carts to be set to ObjectcontainerDS then..
Bind the corresponding Business entity to that container..